# Where does Bitcoin Core implement announcement of blocks optionally by `cmpctblock` or `inv` messages?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-core-development, bandwidth, compact-blocks

In BIP152 implementation note

> Nodes MAY impose additional requirements on when they announce new
> blocks by sending `cmpctblock` messages. For example, nodes with limited
> outbound bandwidth MAY choose to announce new blocks using inv/header
> messages (as per BIP130) to conserve outbound bandwidth.

Where is it implemented in Bitcoin Core?

Comment: Hi masuda, I edited your question to try and capture the main idea of your question in the title. Please feel free to roll-back or further edit, if you feel that it doesn’t match your intent.